# Playbook task using ansible _mount and json_jquery throwing an error

Tags: ansible, devops

I was trying  to use below task to  verify, if the mount point of /dev/vdb partition is /data using ansible_mount.But the below playbook task is throwing me  assertion failed error. could someone suggest me why it is throwing error or  guide me to right way of approach.

P.S : I am not interested in using shell commands

```
 - name: test for disk partitions
    vars:
      mount_data: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?device == `/dev/vdb`].mount') }}"

    assert:
      that:  mount_data == "/data"
      success_msg : "Expected mount point"
```

ansible_mounts looks as below:

```
"ansible_mounts": [
            {
                "block_available": 51550174,
                "block_size": 4096,
                "block_total": 52425979,
                "block_used": 875805,
                "device": "/dev/vda1",
                "fstype": "xfs",
                "inode_available": 104768494,
                "inode_total": 104857072,
                "inode_used": 88578,
                "mount": "/",
                "options": "rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
                "size_available": 211149512704,
                "size_total": 214736809984,
                "uuid": "3ef2b806-efd7-4eef-aaa2-2584909365ff"
            },
            {
                "block_available": 314410952,
                "block_size": 4096,
                "block_total": 314419200,
                "block_used": 8248,
                "device": "/dev/vdb",
                "fstype": "xfs",
                "inode_available": 125829117,
                "inode_total": 125829120,
                "inode_used": 3,
                "mount": "/data",
                "options": "rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
                "size_available": 1287827259392,
                "size_total": 1287861043200,
                "uuid": "5214b6b0-04af-4ce9-ba46-06fa050d315f"
            },
            {
                "block_available": 26193352,
                "block_size": 4096,
                "block_total": 26201600,
                "block_used": 8248,
                "device": "/dev/vdc",
                "fstype": "xfs",
                "inode_available": 52428797,
                "inode_total": 52428800,
                "inode_used": 3,
                "mount": "/var/corefiles",
                "options": "rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
                "size_available": 107287969792,
                "size_total": 107321753600,
                "uuid": "b7f230b1-ec81-4cd6-b2d4-20579eb135c6"
            }
        ],
```

Error which I got while executing the task

```
  FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "uu  == \"uu\"",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
```

Comment: can you show the output ? Can you share whats `ansible_mounts` look like ?

Comment: I could not add ansible_ mounts o/p as a comment. i have appended o/p of ansible_mounts to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jmespath` expression in `json_query` is returning a list of mount points, even though it only returns a single element.

You need to either:

1. check that the first element of the list is equal to your string
2. check that your string is contained in the list

All three solutions below should work:

```yaml
that: mount_data.0 == "/data"
that: mount_data is contains "/data"
that: '"/data" in mount_data'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But I really don't  want to use positions. Any other suggestions?

Comment: second and third solution don't use positions. Meanwhile, using position 0 on a list that will always return a single element is not really using positions. It's only a mean to get the single string value inside it. You can also see the [`first` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first)